# CM7 for Milestone - build from source while kernel.org is down for maintenance

Tags: android, linux

I want to build CM7 for my Milestone but kernel.org being down makes that hard for me since all howtos and repos I found rely on it's existence - anyone knows a quick workaround?
I already asked this question here: http://android.doshaska.net/cm7build - but got no feedback - so perhaps I am lucky here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a copy of CyanogenMod sources on github.com: https://github.com/CyanogenMod
Get the kernel source form there.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a vanilla kernel source, you can extract it from a Debian package called linux-source-2.6.x. Search for linux-source on packages.debian.org. Note that not all versions are available. Ubuntu has similar packages in Launchpad.